# Unity AudioSource.Play() does not work when the AudioSource component is added from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The title pretty much sums up my problem. I am using an `AudioManager` script to play one of the sounds from an array. It seems that all variables have been assigned correctly and I am able to access all the properties of `AudioSource`. However, when I call `Play()`, no sound is heard in the editor. I have also tested this by manually adding a single `AudioSource` component and calling `AudioSource.Play()` from my play method (commented line in `Play()`), and it works just fine. Below are the two scripts in question. I am getting no errors or warnings.

I'm using Unity 2019.3.3f

Update: So I have found the problem, the pitch variable of Sound class was uninitialized so it was defaulting to 0.

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;
    public static AudioManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        if (instance == null) instance = this;
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.audioSource.clip = s.clip;
            s.audioSource.volume = s.volume;
            s.audioSource.pitch = s.pitch;
            s.audioSource.playOnAwake = s.playOnAwake;
        }
    }

    public void Play(string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        s.audioSource.Play();
        // gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Sound
{
    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float volume;
    [Range(-3f, 3f)] public float pitch;
    public bool playOnAwake = false;
    [HideInInspector] public AudioSource audioSource;
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldnt add a soundsource for each clip, I also wouldnt play them all on awake as theres a chance thats happening before the scenes barely loaded

Comment: @BugFinder I want to play overlapping sounds, and as mentioned in the post they are played using a Play() method from my script and not in the Awake method. Should have removed it from awake before I posted, my bad but that was just me testing different possibilities. Ultimately though, I call audioManager.Play() from other scripts on various events such as OnTriggerEnter etc.

Comment: Perhaps the editor is set to "mute audio" or the volume of the sounds is 0?
can you take a screenshot after the instantiation of the audiosources and show them in the inspector?

Comment: Neither is the case. Here is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/qh5hXlx).

Answer (score 0):

When the object is a `DontDestroyOnLoad` object, it loses all of its variables.

Your Solution:
(This is also a whole lot simpler and easy to understand and you also don't need another script)

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AudioSource;
    public static AudioClip clip1, clip2;
    void Awake()
    {
        GameObject[] obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(gameobject.tag);
        if (obj.length > 1)
            Destroy(gameobject);



        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        //Make sure your audioClips are in a folder called "Resources"!!!
        //Put the name of the audio clip in the ""
        clip1 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("clip1");
        clip2 = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("clip2");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Make sure that the gameObject with this script has an audioSource component!
        if (!audioSource)
            audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    //now you can simply call this function from another script using AudioManager.Play("name")
    public static void Play(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "clip1":
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip1);
                break;
            case "clip2":
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I can appreciate a different approach to do this. The real problem was, however, much simpler and a terrible oversight. Updated the question to add the solution. I hadn't tested it on multiple scenes yet, will definitely try your solution once I do get to it. Thanks again!